# How can i increase the reading cursor Speed based WPM values using JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually, I have developed speed reading simulation using JS.

But, my client asked,

**1).** once you get the "word cursor" to be two or three words according to the desired speed. 
The part concerning the "speed reading cursor".

**2).** Once you get the "speed reading cursor" which is equal to the number or words the reader must read at the same time, in order to achieve the desired reading speed.

**For example:** if 120 words a minute. The "speed reading cursor" will be 2 words. Those two words would be displayed in bold at the same time, as the cursor moves thru the reading material at the desired speed.

If on the other hand, the desired speed is 180 words a minute. Or 1.5 times the acceleration speed. Then the "speed reading cursor" will be 3 words. Those 3 words would be moving at the rate of 3 words per minute in bold font.

**3).** As the speed reading cursor starts moving. 
The text that is left behind, will also "dim". It will go into the %70 gray. 
Only the "speed reading cursor" will be displayed in bold font. 
The rest of the text stays. 70% grey.

My Code is in **jsfiddle.net/Darious/m10wff0u/1/**

Could you please how to acceleration the reading?

How can i do it possible?

If any one familiar with JS, please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should i change the formula in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797032/what-should-i-change-the-formula-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with the speed, as it seems when the WPM is increased, the words go slower, but I think that should be easy to fix. I noticed you had both milliseconds and WPM as the same ID so I think that was causing some issues. Here is my fix:

```js
$('#sim').each(function () {
    this.contentEditable = true;
});

var go = $('#go');
var stop = $('#stop');
var wordCount = 0;
var wordCountBox = $('#wordCountBox');
var timepassed = $('#timepassed');
var textRead = $('#textRead');


go.on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startSim();
});

function startSim() {
    var speed = $('#speed').val();
    var boldWords = speed / 60;
    boldWords = boldWords < 1 ? 1 : Math.floor(boldWords);
    timeStart = $.now();
    var sim = $('#sim').text();
    var wordArray = sim.split(" ");
    var simWrap = $('#sim');

    var arrCount = wordArray.length;
    var alreadyRead = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrCount; i++) {
        (function (index) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var pos = index;
                if (pos < 0) {
                    pos = 0;
                }
                alreadyRead.push(wordArray[pos]);
                wordArray[pos] = '<span class="grayx">' + wordArray[pos] + '</span>';
                if (pos > (boldWords - 1)) {
                    wordArray[pos - boldWords] = wordArray[pos - boldWords].replace("x", "dim");
                }
                var words = wordArray.join(" ");
                simWrap.html(words);
                wordCount++;
                if (pos == (arrCount - 1)) {
                    triggerDone();
                }
                $('#sim b:last')[0].scrollIntoView(false);
            }, i * speed);
        })(i);
    }
    // Function done
    function triggerDone() {
        wordCountBox.text(wordCount + ' Words Read');
        var timeEnd = $.now();
        var timeRes = timeEnd - timeStart;
        timeRes = parseInt(timeRes);
        timeRes = timeRes / 1000;
        timepassed.text(timeRes + " seconds have passed");
        alreadyRead = alreadyRead.join("");
        textRead.text(alreadyRead);
        var summary = $('#summary');
        summary.show();
        return;
    }
    stop.on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        triggerDone();
    });
}
```

```css
#sim {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    border:solid 1px #2e2e2e;
    color:#B3B3B3;
    padding:5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:9px outset #0ADA0A;
    margin-top:1em;
    font-size:16pt;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#333;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap : 20px;
    -moz-column-rule-color: #ccc;
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
    -webkit-column-rule-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
}
button {
    padding:10px 25px;
    color:#fafafa;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#go {
    background-color:#46A111;
    border:solid 1px #46A111;
}
#go:hover {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#46A111;
}
#stop {
    background-color:#A11111;
    border:solid 1px #A11111;
}
#stop:hover {
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#A11111;
}
.grayx {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.graydim {
    color: dimgray;
}
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="milliseconds" type="number" value="1000" step="25" min="0" max="1000" />
<label for="speed">in milliseconds</label>
<button id="go">START</button>
<button id="stop">STOP</button>
<input id="speed" type="number" value="300" step="10" min="0" max="1000" />
<label for="speed">WPM</label>
<div id="sim" cols="2" rows="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur diam nisi, auctor id pulvinar vel, commodo sit amet dui. Nulla cursus vitae est ut fringilla. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla molestie, orci nec congue laoreet, velit orci volutpat nulla, non sollicitudin nulla magna vel justo. Curabitur in orci id lorem porttitor eleifend in in nibh. Phasellus vitae quam tellus. Morbi porttitor magna nec nunc euismod, ac fermentum nisi vulputate. Etiam efficitur, metus sit amet iaculis tempor, mauris sem molestie neque, vitae faucibus lorem justo vel metus. Curabitur id laoreet ligula, eget tempus nunc. Etiam ultricies tortor ut elit elementum, id vestibulum magna vestibulum. Donec ut hendrerit magna. Quisque in nibh sit amet turpis varius sollicitudin nec euismod lorem. Etiam vitae pulvinar nibh. Nullam porttitor nulla finibus, tempus tortor suscipit, blandit risus. Praesent porta gravida nisi non scelerisque. Aliquam vel condimentum neque. Nullam ac arcu posuere, imperdiet neque ac, dignissim felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed facilisis dignissim purus. Nulla efficitur quis lacus sed efficitur. Curabitur viverra, metus eget suscipit efficitur, orci nibh molestie enim, eget bibendum mi ex sed ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec consequat urna velit, et rutrum lorem laoreet ac. In sapien turpis, efficitur condimentum lacinia a, imperdiet ut nisi. Aenean eget tincidunt arcu. Vestibulum nisi neque, molestie sed eleifend sit amet, porttitor ut nisi. Vestibulum ultricies auctor nunc, condimentum feugiat lectus malesuada sit amet. Nam dignissim scelerisque lorem id auctor. Nullam nec urna eget dolor eleifend fermentum. Mauris dapibus est quis lorem eleifend tempor. Praesent vel laoreet ipsum. Nulla condimentum, tellus sed sodales posuere, nisl velit hendrerit diam, in dictum tortor velit eu tellus. Aliquam lectus enim, laoreet at interdum vitae, facilisis quis sapien. Nullam dignissim tristique quam, id tempus dui cursus nec. Donec varius massa sagittis pretium ultrices. Nam laoreet tincidunt ex, ut vestibulum nisl ultricies at. Etiam gravida viverra metus, quis mattis sapien egestas nec. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nam et iaculis ex, a efficitur enim. Quisque facilisis volutpat nisi sed malesuada. Sed porttitor justo vitae tortor porttitor, nec imperdiet nisl consectetur. Morbi scelerisque aliquam semper. Vivamus pulvinar quam felis, vitae laoreet risus suscipit sed. Vestibulum tincidunt convallis dapibus. Fusce ut efficitur erat. Proin venenatis, nibh eu rutrum pretium, ante turpis fermentum nibh, et ullamcorper eros dolor et ipsum. Sed ut justo leo. Nam vel auctor libero. Nam sed dui at arcu porta laoreet vitae quis ligula. Aenean facilisis neque eu venenatis rutrum. Praesent id tincidunt justo, ornare dapibus lectus. Ut consectetur maximus enim, eget tempus mauris dapibus iaculis. Fusce consequat ligula ac tincidunt consectetur.</div>
<div class="summary" id="summary">
    <p id="wordCountBox"></p>
    <p id="timepassed"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @oMiKeY... Tons of Thanks to you.

Comment: Hi @oMiKeY, small doubt on this, why last word shows bold, after read?