# What should i change the formula in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a speed reading simulation using HTML5 and JS.

But, i could not understand client expectation.

I have used the below for the app.

```js
$('#sim').each(function () {
    this.contentEditable = true;
});

var go = $('#go');
var stop = $('#stop');
var wordCount = 0;
var wordCountBox = $('#wordCountBox');
var timepassed = $('#timepassed');
var textRead = $('#textRead');


go.on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    startSim();
});

function startSim() {
    var speed = $('#speed').val();
    var boldWords = speed / 60;
    boldWords = boldWords < 1 ? 1 : Math.round(boldWords);
    timeStart = $.now();
    var sim = $('#sim').text();
    var wordArray = sim.split(/[\s]+/);
    var simWrap = $('#sim');

    var arrCount = wordArray.length;
    var alreadyRead = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arrCount; i++) {
        (function (index) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var pos = index;
                if (pos < 0) {
                    pos = 0;
                }
                alreadyRead.push(wordArray[pos]);
                wordArray[pos] = '<span class="grayx">' + wordArray[pos] + '</span>';
                if (pos > (boldWords - 1)) {
                    wordArray[pos - boldWords] = wordArray[pos - boldWords].replace("x", "dim");
                }
                var words = wordArray.join(" ");
                simWrap.html(words);
                wordCount++;
                if (pos == (arrCount - 1)) {
                    triggerDone();
                }
                $('#sim span:last')[0].scrollIntoView(false);
            }, i * speed);
        })(i);
    }
    // Function done
    function triggerDone() {
        wordCountBox.text(wordCount + ' Words Read');
        var timeEnd = $.now();
        var timeRes = timeEnd - timeStart;
        timeRes = parseInt(timeRes);
        timeRes = timeRes / 1000;
        timepassed.text(" in " + timeRes + " Seconds.");
        alreadyRead = alreadyRead.join("");
        textRead.text(alreadyRead);
        var summary = $('#summary');
        summary.show();
        return;
    }
    stop.on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        triggerDone();
    });
}
```

```css
#sim {
    width:800px;
    height:400px;
    border:solid 1px #2e2e2e;
    color:black;
    padding:5px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    border:9px outset #0ADA0A;
    margin-top:1em;
    font-size:16pt;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:white;
    column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap : 20px;
    -moz-column-rule-color: #ccc;
    -moz-column-rule-style: solid;
    -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;
    -webkit-column-rule-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-column-rule-style: solid;
    -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;
}
button{
    padding:10px 25px;
    color:#fafafa;
    transition:all 0.3s;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#go{
    background-color:#46A111;
    border:solid 1px #46A111;
}
#go:hover{
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#46A111;
}
#stop{
    background-color:#A11111;
    border:solid 1px #A11111;
}
#stop:hover{
    background-color:#fafafa;
    color:#A11111;
}
.summary{
width:350px;
height:30px;
margin-left:12em;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border:solid 1px #2e2e2e;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none;
    border-radius: 45px;
    background: #8AC007;
    padding: 5px;   
    
    
}
#bold{
    font-weight:bold;
}
.grayx {
    font-weight: 600;
}
.graydim {
    color: dimgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summary" id="summary">
                    <span id="wordCountBox"></span>
                    <span id="timepassed"></span>                    
                </div>
<button id="go">START</button>
        <button id="stop">STOP</button>
<input id="speed" type="number" value="120" step="10" min="0" max="1000"/>
                <span for="speed">WPM</span>
<div id="sim" cols="2" rows="2"></div>
```

OR

http://jsfiddle.net/Darious/dcu808w1/

**Updated**

**But my client wants**,

> With a two word cursor.   1200 divided by two: 600 words.
>
> 600 words divided by 60 seconds
>
> That would be 10 minutes
>
> Right ?
>
> With a three word cursor.
>
> 1200 div by 3 = 400 words
>
> 400 div by 60 seconds = 6.66 minutes.
>
> When you get that working. You can add a button for the Cursor time
>   speed.
>
> First 1 second
>
> Then .5 second
>
> For now. The values are :
>
> .25, .5, .75, 1, 1.25, 1.50, 2

Really, I don't know, What should i change on this?

Comment: @humble.rumble this has nothing to do with random.

Comment: @humble.rumble that depends on your definition of `variable`. by reading the rest of the post, you can figure out that the desired behavior depends on a fixed formula, taking the number of words and reading speed as input. it has nothing to do with randomness.

Comment: or in simpler terms : `variable != random`

Comment: help me with brief explanation.

Comment: You appear to be trying to get [SO to do your work for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30681621/how-can-i-increase-the-reading-cursor-speed-based-wpm-values-using-javascript). If you can't do what your client wants, perhaps it's time to tell them that.

Comment: [and another duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705439/how-can-i-import-a-csv-datas-to-html-form-with-editing-adding-new-using-javascr?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can figure out is this :

```
boldWords = boldWords < 1 ? 1 : Math.floor(boldWords);
```

returns 1 in the case described (where `boldWords` begins as `~1.67`) , but geussing from your client's wishes, he expects an outcome of 2.
Simply change it to

```
boldWords = boldWords < 1 ? 1 : Math.round(boldWords);
```

(or use `Math.ceil`, don't know about any further requirements, and if that would fit them)

Comment: help me with brief explanation.

Comment: your formula seems to work ok, but you are probably rounding the result the wrong way.